# How to get a Backbone Model attribute after fetch?

Tags: backbone.js, web, frameworks

I know that a fetch is asynchronous and it needs to use "success" in fetch.
But what if I want to use the data out of the success?
I wanna to get the user ID and to use it in a model "Note".

```
 authedUser.fetch({
            success: function(){;
                window.uid = authedUser.get("id");
            }
```

But if I try to do this console.log(uid); not in success I get **undefined**.

Comment: Can you show a bit more code?  Not sure what you need, but "authedUser" won't have any data until after the success method runs.

Comment: I am getting the data (id, name, email) from server and put it in authedUser model with fetch. it works great. But I want to get the user id and use it not only in "success". For instance, in another model.

Comment: You're probably going to want to research Async vs. synchronized fetches.  You're probably trying to use window.uid while the fetch operation is still going on.

Answer (score 0):

When your new models/collections are registered the "change" event is triggered.

So you can use

```
 MyModel.on("change", function() {

    MyModel.get('wtv');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access updated model from success callback.
Like this:

```
authedUser.fetch({
        success: function(model){;
            window.uid = model.get("id");
        }
```